# Windowed XAML App

Tags: c++, .net, xaml, windows-8, visual-studio-2012

I want to make a windowed app in XAML on Windows 8 in C++, but the only XAML options as far as I can tell are Metro (casual) apps (full screen). However, my app is not a casual app, and as such I want it to be a desktop (windowed) app. Also, I would like Window 7 users who hate Windows 8 to be able to use it.

Is there any way? Changing `<Page ... </Page>` to `<Window ... </Window>` doesn't seem to fix the issue (at least for me). I know Visual Studio 2012 can do Windowed XAML C# as I opened a project from a while back and it runs windowed.

Is this just a project setting or what?

Comment: WPF is still available in Windows 8 with Visual Studio 2010 or Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: The key word(s) is C++. You can't make XAML C++ apps with the designer in WPF

Comment: That's logical; WPF is completely managed code. Sorry I missed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: It's not a project setting; you're attempting something that was never supported. C++ is not a WPF language. You'll need to use C# or Visual Basic to build a WPF Desktop app, which is supported both in VS2012 and VS2010. Sorry I missed the fact that you're working in C++.

---

(C# should not be a steep learning curve, if you haven't used it before and you're used to C++. And you can port C++ over in CLR libraries if needed.)

Probably, it's just a project setting, and it depends on the version of Visual Studio you have. I think the Express versions of Visual Studio 2012 only permit the creation of "Metro-style" apps, while the Professional, Premier, or Ultimate editions have desktop (WPF or Silverlight) target projects.

To be sure, start up a new solution and see if you're given the choice. If not, you probably don't have the right version of VS2012. Be sure to check down the treeview of project types to make sure that you haven't missed one. If it's really the Professional version of VS2012, it'll be in there or it'll be downloadable.

Comment: Wait... VS11 was the prerelease codename for what became Visual Studio 2012, right?

Comment: there is also a Visual Studio Express 2012 for Desktop supporting WPF, Windows Forms, and Win32

Comment: @JimONeil I have used C# and I like Skeet, but being able to manually manage pointers and all that low level stuff is what makes C++ the choice for me. Granted, when writing a .NET DLL, I will use C# because C++/CLR has some features that C# doesn't (pointers). That could cause problems with someone who uses it in a C# app

Comment: @ColeJohnson C# has pointers. And the whole "modern C++" thing is trying to get as far away as possible from pointers and low level stuff. For more details, come to the [Lounge](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/loungec), we'll brainwash you.

Comment: @EtienneDeMartel yes I know it does. But they are a pain to work with thanks to garbage collection. I understand you can use `fixed` but its still a pain.

Comment: @ColeJohnson That's because you're not supposed to use pointers. And this is true for C++, too.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel I like being able to manually manage my objects and not have a garbage collector getting in the way. Also, on low level stuff, how am I supposed to use the AES new instructions in C#?

Comment: @ColeJohnson: What does not using raw pointers have to do with GC?

Comment: @sbi The use of `fixed` and such are a real pain.

Comment: @sbi To use pointers in C#, you need to use `fixed`, and the GC will move an object eventually (ruining your pointer) if you forget to use `fixed`. In C++, there is no GC, so there is nothing to move your object around destroying your pointer. Also, in C++, I can use the AES new instructions, CPUID, etc. And C++ is platform independent, whereas C# needs the runtime and Mono doesn't have WPF. Don't mention Moonlight as Silverlight is deprecated now with Win 8.

Comment: @sbi My question was not `Can someone convert me from C++ism to C#ism?` but `Can I make a windowed C++ app in XAML?`

Comment: I recommend modifying the title of your question to include "C++" someplace.